# Autosize UILabel height with UIImageView Interface Builder MonoTouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, uiimageview, interface-builder, uilabel, autolayout

I come from an Android background where I would use `height = wrap_content` to solve my problem. I have a `UILabel` and `UIImageView` just below this label as a border on the bottom. However, I'm not sure how long of text the label will be and when the label becomes to large there is a problem. I have tried setting

```
Label.Lines = 0;
Label.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
Label.SizeToFit();
```

This wraps the `Label` if it grows more than one line but then it overlaps the image below it.

So my question is, how do I make the label height dependent on the text and show everything down below it? I have looked at many SO Q&A and they comment about `AutoLayout` and `Constraints` in Interface Builder and some say you must calculate the height of the label and push everything else down in the code? But none of them are clear about steps to accomplish this (especially in MonoTouch)

Also, this content is in a `ScrollView` so I'm assuming I'm going to have to calculate each label height on my page in order to set the content size of the scrollview?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a bottom constraint to the label and the image, so that the bottom margin is maintained and the image view is pushed down when the label expands.

To add a constraint you need to select the view to add constraint in the storyboard and on the right hand side select the red lines under add new constraint as shown in the image.

[image: constraint image]

If in you case the scroll view consist of only a label and a image view you can try adding left , right , top and bottom margins to both the label and image and the scroll view would automatically adjust the content size.

But make sure scroll view height is not greater than the screen height. i.e; you need to set the left , right , top and bottom margins to zero.

[image]

To summarize it :

1. Open storyboard file.
2. Add left right top and bottom margin to 0 for the scroll view.
3. Add left right top and bottom margin to  a suitable value for label.
4. Add left right top and bottom margin to  a suitable value for image view.